# Loading files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, load

In my code I want to indicate paths to files that are independent on which computer the code is run. In other words, I want the script to operate only in the folder where it is located because my friend's computer can have different drive names, folders' names etc. The task is to load files by indicating where they are located. I thought this would work: "**load("..\Folder\file.mat")**". However, Matlab gives an error

```
Error using load

'..\Folder\file.mat' is not found in the current folder or on the MATLAB path, but exists in:

D:\D (synced)\Folder 3\Matlab

D:\D (synced)\Folder 3\Data

Change the MATLAB current folder or add its folder to the MATLAB path.
```

I checked and file.mat is in Folder which is located in the same directory as the script that I run.
**Could someone tell how to make all paths independent on what computer they are run and avoid the error?**

Comment: Your command will correctly load the file, if it is where it is specified to be. Based on the error message, it looks like the file is not where it was expected, but Matlab is amking some guesses as to what you might have meant. Using a relative path like you are doing means that the performance will change, depending on the current Matlab working directory. This is usually the expected behavior, but may not be in your particular case. We probably need more to work with here.

Comment: Can you add  `disp(pwd());ls('../Folder')` to the top of your code to see where we really are?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that both your script and file are in the folder Folder.
To make it operating system independent, you could use `mfilename` to retrieve the path of your script, and use `fullfile` to concatenate the path with the file name.

```
p = mfilename( 'fullpath');
file = load( fullfile( p, 'file.mat'));
```